# custom timescale docker image build is failing run the postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying custom timescale db docker image.

Dockerfile is as below;

```
FROM timescale/timescaledb:2.11.0-pg14
COPY ./init/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

when I run this, im getting below error.

```
psql localhost
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the docker command you're using to run the container?

Comment: docker run -d postgres1
 exits without throwing any error in the logs.

so i tried 
docker run -it --rm  --entrypoint /bin/sh postgres1
#psql localhost

got this error
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?